mostrar/ocultar tabla
Estoy intentando crear un boton de mostrar/ocultar una tabla. La tabla al principio se imprime asi: 
Pero, luego de darle click al boton de mostrar/ocultar tabla. La tabla se muestra asi

Este es la funcion que uso para mostrar o ocultar la tabla en javascript:


function mostrarOcultar(id) {
    var elemento = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!elemento) {
        return true;
    }
    if (elemento.style.display == "none") {
        elemento.style.display = "block";
        // Mostrar el tbody al mostrar la tabla
        var tbody = elemento.querySelector("tbody");
        if (tbody) {
            tbody.style.display = "table-row-group";
        }
    } else {
        elemento.style.display = "none";
        // Ocultar el tbody al ocultar la tabla
        var tbody = elemento.querySelector("tbody");
        if (tbody) {
            tbody.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    return true;
}

Esto es el html donde genero el boton y llamo a la funcion 
 <div class="bg-dark text-light text-center border-top wow fadeIn" id="resultadoEncriptarContainer2" style="display: none;">
            <button onclick="return mostrarOcultar('toggleTableBtn')" class="btn btn-primary">Mostrar/ocultar tabla</button>
            <p id="resultadoEncriptar" style="display: none;"></p>
            <div>
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered mt-5" id="toggleTableBtn" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Caracter</th>
                            <th>Valor</th>
                            <th>Operacion</th>
                            <th>Valor</th>
                            <th>Caracter</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tablaEncriptacionBody">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>




En lugar de todo eso, al ser bootstrap, puedes hacerlo así, usando la clase d-none y la propiedad classList del elemento:


function mostrarOcultar(id) {
  var elemento = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!elemento) {
    return true;
  }
  elemento.classList.toggle("d-none");
  return true;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.3.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="bg-dark text-light text-center border-top wow fadeIn" id="resultadoEncriptarContainer2">
  <button onclick="return mostrarOcultar('toggleTableBtn')" class="btn btn-primary">Mostrar/ocultar tabla</button>
  <p id="resultadoEncriptar" style="display: none;"></p>
  <div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered mt-5" id="toggleTableBtn">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Caracter</th>
          <th>Valor</th>
          <th>Operacion</th>
          <th>Valor</th>
          <th>Caracter</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tablaEncriptacionBody">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>



